# In Android, is there a similar method to the repaint() in java?

Tags: android

In Android, is there a similar method to the repaint() in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `postInvalidate`, not `invalidate`. As repaint() can be called by both UI and non-UI thread. So does `postInvalidate`.

Answer (score 2):

To force a view to draw, call [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/view/View.html)().

Comment: yes, i came across that but couldnt figure out how to use it.. wat oblect do i use to call it?

Comment: the view you want to repaint, you get a reference to the view by findViewById

Comment: I think should be postInvalidate, as invalidate can be only called by UI thread.